# Refreshing FB post preview image

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph

We've created a post on Facebook where we've linked to a page on our website. Since then the page that was linked was changed and the og:image url was changed. Unfortunately, the post on the FB timeline still contains data for old image (in this case, a broken image is displayed). How can I refresh the image that is displaying on FB timeline for given post?

What I've tried so far:

- going to https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/sharing/, entering the page URL, clicking on "Scrape Again"; result: image didn't change on both debug page / FB timeline
- adding og:updated_time to page in question, repeating the steps above; result: image did change on debug page / but not on FB timeline
- going to https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object/, clicking on "Fetch new scrape information"; result: no change was observed
- sharing original post on my personal timeline; result: observed was broken image being displayed, but after clicking "Refresh share attachment" a correct image was displayed; still that didn't affect the original post in question

Comment: _“still that didn't affect the original post in question”_ - you have to use “refresh share attachment” on that original post. (And most likely on individual shares as well - there is no auto-update that would do this without the person that made the post originally requesting it.)

Comment: There's no "Refresh share attachment" on the original post when viewing it as the owner of that post; I can only refresh the image if I'll share given post (but that of course refreshes my share, not the original post in question).

Comment: Go to the single view of the post, then the option should be available.

Comment: Excellent! If you'll submit this as an answer I'll be happy to accept it. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> but after clicking "Refresh share attachment" a correct image was displayed; still that didn't affect the original post in question

You have to use “refresh share attachment” on that original post. (And most likely on individual shares as well - there is no auto-update that would do this without the person that made the post originally requesting it.)

Go to the single view of the post, there the option should be available. (Directly in news feed, it does not seem to be available all the time.)